# Prevent replay attack while using implicit grant in Identity server4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

How can I mitigate replay attack?
My Website’s callback URL can be easily replayed to get a valid token .
I have seen in the OAuth 2 and identify server documents that we can prevent this by adding nonce.

I am using identitserver 4 and angular 6/ aspcore API.
How can I use nonce to verify and mitigate the attack?

If so, where to validate the nonce (identity server side or in the client side “Angular”.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a nonce and validating it then you're not using the OpenID Connect protocol.

In simple terms you generate a random number, send it in the authorize request as well as temporarily storing it locally and then check that the resulting id_token contains a nonce with a matching value. This verifies that the callback relates to the request you just issued and therefore the same callback request cannot be used again.

Comment: I understood the nonce validation flow. However, OpenID connect internally includes the nonce in every authorise request. How can I access the nonce value from the authorise request.

Comment: I am using oidc-client in the client side.

Comment: That library will almost certainly be doing that validation already. If you want to access the nonce that’s returned then it’s simply a claim in the returned id_token. Not sure if you can access the generated value prior to the auth request being dispatched though.